# How to set looping number in PHPExcel with Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, phpexcel

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MjoTY.png)

how to loop number in phpexcel?

i use codeigniter.

```
$rs = $this->db->get('inventory_barang');
$exceldata="";
foreach ($rs->result_array() as $row){
$exceldata[] = $row;
}

//How should i do for looping 
$this->excel->getActiveSheet()->fromArray('I want number to be looping for column A from A4', null, 'A4');

// read data to active sheet
$this->excel->getActiveSheet()->fromArray($exceldata, null, 'B4');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add number to your array:

```
$rs = $this->db->get('inventory_barang');
$exceldata = [];
foreach ($rs->result_array() as $key=>$row){
    $exceldata[] = array_merge([$key], $row);
}
$this->excel->getActiveSheet()->fromArray($exceldata, null, 'A4');
```